live stream only starts when initiated before app start / Flutter & AWS
I am using in flutter the video_player 2.8.5 (https://pub.dev/packages/video_player).
And I configurated in AWS a live-stream, this gives me a url: https://xxxxxxxx.m3u8
I used the example code from here (https://pub.dev/packages/video_player), see below.
If I start the AWS live-stream before starting the App, the stream runs well. => :-)
If the App is started first... then there is no stream / no error ... nothing. => :-(
If I click on restart (green circle in vs-code) the stream will appear in the app. => :-)
Is there any solution for this problem? So that the stream automatically starts even if the App is started first? Thank you for your help.
===========================================
Here the code from "https://pub.dev/packages/video_player", which I am using, modified only with the AWS-Adress (1 line modified).
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
void main() => runApp(const VideoApp());
/// Stateful widget to fetch and then display video content.
class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
const VideoApp({super.key});
@override
_VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}
class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
late VideoPlayerController _controller;
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(
//'``https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4``'  // stream from the example
'``https://xxxxxxxx.m3u8``' // stream from AWS
))
..initialize().then(() {
// Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
setState(() {});
});
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
title: 'Video Demo',
home: Scaffold(
body: Center(
child: _controller.value.isInitialized
? AspectRatio(
aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
)
: Container(),
),
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
onPressed: () {
setState(() {
_controller.value.isPlaying
? _controller.pause()
: _controller.play();
});
},
child: Icon(
_controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
),
),
),
);
}
@override
void dispose() {
_controller.dispose();
super.dispose();
}
}`
I expected the live-stream starts, even if it is initialized after the app is started...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
